# Calling a method from within a class - not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I've got a class, commenter, and two methods within that class, SaveBtn_Click - created primarily not by me, and then also PeerReview, primarily created by me.

Anyway, the code starts off like this (after a variety of using statements):

```
public partial class commenter : System.Web.UI.Page

    {
        string employee_reviewed;
        PeerReview pr = new PeerReview();
        public void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //all the information for the SaveBtn_Click method. 
        }
```

After that, I have PeerReview:

```
 public void PeerReview(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox listbox)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=hourtracking;uid=username;password=password");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select first_name from employee where active_status=1", con);
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        Console.WriteLine("Another test!");
        Console.WriteLine(r);
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, this is a test!");
        while (r.Read())
        {
            listbox.Items.Add(new ListItem(Convert.ToString(r["first_name"]), Convert.ToString(r["first_name"])));

        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

I'm connecting this with ASP.NET, and I can get the listbox to show up, but not the individual items in the listbox. I'm testing it with a console.writeline command, to see if that outputs anything - but nothing is being put out on the ASP page.

I'm not certain how I should reference these particular sections (new to C#, asking like 3 dozen questions about this).

ASP code looks like this:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="listBox1" runat="server">
```

Comment: Did you *expect* `Console.WriteLine` to write output to the page?

Comment: Console.WriteLine isn't ASP.Net, that's for a windows Console app.

Comment: Yes, Jon. I'm still very new to ASP.NET and C# - all of my web work has been in PHP or Python.

Comment: Well Console.WriteLine isn't going to do anything, remove it.

Comment: If you are testing and need to see on the page, use [Response.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead of  `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: Better yet, just attach the debugger and view your properties. Click in the left hand bar of your code behind and that adds a break point. Appologies if I'm stating the obvious.

Comment: Console.WriteLine will output in the console window of Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

You have some confused declarations.

You declare a *method* called PeerReview, but you also have an attempt to create an instance of PeerReview as though it were a *type*. I think you really just want to call the PeerReview method from your button click event, eg

```
public void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           PeerReview();
        }
```

And then eliminate the "PeerReview pr = new PeerReview();" line. Also, as this is on a page, you have an implicit reference within the partial class to the listbox by its ID, so you don't need to pass it as a parameter. And the Console.WriteLines are not useful in a web application - you might try Response.Write if you're wanting to add that to the output for debug purposes.

**Edits based on OP response**

You should call PeerReview in the Page_Load event handler:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You need to determine if you should call PeerReview every time the page 
    // loads, or only on the initial call of the page, thus determining whether
    // you need the IsPostBack() test. My instinct is that you *do* want to constrain
    // it to the first pass, but only you can make that determination for
    // certain based on your requirements.

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)  //Do you need this check?
    {
        PeerReview();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I want the PeerReview listbox to be filled in BEFORE clicking the submit button. They're unrelated.

The listbox is for a list of employee names, so that something can be submitted for that specific employee, and not just generically.

Comment: Then I would think you need to call PeerReview() in the Page_Load event. You'd also need to determine if you should call it only on the first call to the page, or if it should be inhibited in the postback that occurs when your button handler fires in response to the click event...

Comment: And Page_Load should be a method of the commenter class, correct?

Comment: Yes. It is a default event handler that exists by virtue of the class deriving from Page.

Comment: C# and ASP.NET are so much more different than PHP and Python coding!

Comment: LOL yeah, they are, although I must admit that *original* or "Classic" ASP was closer to PHP than ASP.NET :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

quick view here is you are adding items to `listbox` instead of `listBox1`

change:

```
 listbox.Items.Add(new ListItem(Convert.ToString(r["first_name"]), Convert.ToString(r["first_name"])));
```

to:

```
 listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Convert.ToString(r["first_name"]), Convert.ToString(r["first_name"])));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add items to listbox though your listBox has an id of listBox1

Rather than looping through your data and adding items why not bind the datasource to your listbox and then set the DataTextField and DataValueField on your listbox.

So for example (typos may exist..sorry.. been a while since i wrote C#)

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=hourtracking;uid=username;password=password");
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select first_name from employee where active_status=1", con);
    con.Open();
    MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    listBox1.DataSource = r;
    listBox1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
```

If you can't bind to the reader (can't remember..) then dump your results into a datatable first, then bind to the listBox1

```
    DataTable dTable = New DataTable();
    dTable.Load(reader);
    listBox1.DataSource = dTable;
    listBox1.DataBind();
```

in your asp, set the listBox fields like:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="listBox1" runat="server" DataTextField="first_name" DataValueField="first_name">
```